# SEPA and my name

Tags: eur-euro, european-union, europe

It's the first time that I want to use SEPA payment method, I want to transfer 500€ from my bank account at Austria to France, I want to know, Is my name will be displayed on beneficiary statement?

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what the true motivation of your question is as to give you a really helpful answer. But yes, sender data (name of the sending account holder) is always provided. Everything else would open the door to money laundering.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the practise and applications available with the Beneficiary Bank. For a corporate customer, the details are show. For Retail customers they are generally not shown.

Comment: This is not my experience. I think for any SEPA payment I have received, the name of the sender is mentioned (not full address details though).